# How to get all role combinations, from a list, when roles can be combined to other roles

Tags: c#, algorithm, permutation, combinatorics

**Context**: Consider a game where you have N 6-sided dice. Each side of a die represents a roll: command (COM), science (SCI), engineer (ENG), medical (MED), security (SEC), and a side not used for this problem. A goal of the game is to use the dice on challenge cards, which list different roles required to resolve the challenge. For instance, I may have a challenge card that requires 1 COM, 1 SCI, and 1 MED. So if I roll dice and get 1 COM, 1 SCI, and 1 MED, I can apply them to the challenge card to resolve the challenge.

**Additional Rules**: Along with the 1:1 mapping of a dice roles to challenge card requirements, dice can also be combined to *change* their roles in the following manner:

1. 2 MED can become 1 SCI; 2 SCI can become 1 MED.
2. 2 ENG can become 1 SEC; 2 SEC can become 1 ENG.
3. A COM role + any other role can become any role. So COM + SEC can become ENG.
4. Any three roles can become a different role. So COM + SEC + ENG can become MED.

**Problem**: I want to generate the list of all possible dice combinations for a challenge card's requirements. As an example, say a challenge card requires 1 SCI, 1 ENG, and 1 MED. By hand, I see that I'll need:

if 1 SCI, 1 ENG, and 1 MED, done  (A, B, C)
if 1 SCI, 1 ENG, and 2 SCI, done  (A, B, D)
if 1 SCI, 1 ENG, and COM and other, done  (A, B, E)
if 1 SCI, 1 ENG, and 3 other, done  (A, B, F)

if 1 SCI, 2 SEC, and 1 MED, done  (A, G, C)
if 1 SCI, 2 SEC, and 2 SCI, done  (A, G, D)
if 1 SCI, 2 SEC, and COM and other, done  (A, G, E)
if 1 SCI, 2 SEC, and 3 other, done  (A, G, F)

if 1 SCI, COM and other, and 1 MED, done  (A, E, C)
if 1 SCI, COM and other, and 2 SCI, done  (A, E, D)
if 1 SCI, COM and other, and COM and other, done  (A, E, E)
if 1 SCI, COM and other, and 3 other, done  (A, E, F)

if 1 SCI, 3 other, and 1 MED, done  (A, F, C)
if 1 SCI, 3 other, and 2 SCI, done  (A, F, D)
if 1 SCI, 3 other, and COM and other, done  (A, F, E)
if 1 SCI, 3 other, and 3 other, done  (A, F, F)

Further, I'd need to replace the initial 1 SCI with 2 MED, COM + other device, and 3 other device with the same groupings.

**Question**: Despite the examples, I'm struggling to derive an algorithm I can code against. Can someone offer an algorithm that can incorporate swapping roles for other roles as part of a list of all valid combinations?

Comment: Fix me if I'm wrong, just raising a thought, all the ways to create this challenge card is all the ways to create each one of the components in the card?

Comment: Another thing you should think about is creating a function that can tell you if from this set of roles you can create this card instead of creating all of the combinations. (since if you need 9 cards for some combination you have about 6^9 options which is about 10 million). If you do decide to implement this function you can do this by some sort of BFS algorithm. Tell me and I will write a more informative answer :)

Comment: @Yonlif - It's an interesting idea to go in the other direction (given the dice assigned to the card, determine if they meet the challenge). But the next step, once this algorithm is resolved, is to identify which challenge dice requirements have been met and which haven't. Thus, having a list of all challenge combinations (for a card) seemed useful for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can represent this as a grammar.  Your starting state is the nominal (straightforward) challenge requirements.  Your edges represent valid transitions from that state to another state, each one showing the inverse transition.

For instance, for your card (SCI, ENG, MED), you will start with that state of three elements.  You will now include states (combinations) reachable with each of your transition rules:

```
SCI => [MED, MED]
MED => [SCI, SCI]
b => [COM, a] for any (a, b), where a != b
d => [a, b, c] for any (a, b, c, d) where a, b, c, != d
```

You can express each of these rules as a function.  Keep a list of states (combinations) already reached.  Treat the problem as a graph traversal, and use the standard algorithms to find the graph's closure from your given start state.  For starters:

```
(SCI, ENG, MED)
apply rule 1
(ENG, MED^3) push this to your `search` list
apply rule 2
(SCI^3, ENG) push this to your `search` list
apply rule 3 to "SCI"
(a, COM, ENG, MED) for all `a` != "SCI"; push these ...
```

See where this is going?

At each pass, you take the first item off the list, ring the changes on it with the rules, pushing any new states onto the list.  You need to keep track of states you've already processed, and make a check that you don't exceed `N` elements in each state.

Can you work from that outline?